# Jekyll on github pages display division result as a fraction

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm building a blog running on jekyll and github pages.
I'm trying to display reading time of each post in this way: (assuming average reading speed is 180 words per minute)

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
    {% capture readtime %}{{ post.content | number_of_words | plus:91 | divided_by:180 }}{% endcapture %}
    ...
    {{ readtime }} min. read
{% endfor %}
```

When I test this code locally everything is fine. For a post with 200 words:
291 / 180 = 1.61(6)
jekyll generates the result:

```
1 min. read
```

But when I push this code to github pages, something weird happens. As a result of division I see some fraction which would give me the same result. 
So jekyll on github generates the result:

```
97/60 min. read
```

In fact:
97 / 60 = 1.61(6)

What should I do to have the same result on github as I have locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug.

This works

```
{% assign number = 200 %}
{{ number | divided_by: 10 }}
```

outputs : 20

This doesn't work

```
{% assign text = "a text with words" %}
{% assign division = text | number_of_words | divided_by: 3 %}
{{ division }}
```

outputs : **4/3**

I have filled bugs in both [Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2702) and [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/408) repositories and I'll post here as soon as I have informations about the resolution.

Considering that this bug is reproduced on github page and knowing how serious is the github community I bet that we'll soon have this bug tackled.

Edit :

This is a Jekyll bug that is now fixed in master branch. We now have to wait for this commit to be realized in next Jekyll version, I suppose v2.1 and then bubble to Github pages.

Stay tuned.